# How do I get all available form field types?

Tags: 6, forms

How do I get all form field types (e.g. "textbox," "select") available in Drupal 6?

Comment: You can find the list of all core elements here: [Drupal 6](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6) [Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core fields are provided by [`hook_elements`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_elements/6) so you can just invoke that hook to get a list of all field types in the site using [`module_invoke_all()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/6):

```
 $all_types = module_invoke_all('elements');
```

The array keys of `$all_types` are the machine names of the elements, each of those points to another array containing the element information.